# How will the developer stop burning of the token in future prior to running out of token?

Tags: solidity

In deflationary smart contract, How will the developer stop burning of the token in future prior to running out of token. I believe smart contract cannot be changed after deployment. Please I need  enlightening regarding it.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which specific smart contract you're referring to.
Most deflationary smart contracts implement the burning into specific user-actions such as performing transactions since there's no such thing as CronJobs on blockchains.

If you burn a percentage of a transaction, you will never "run out of tokens", so there's no need to "stop" the burning.

> I believe smart contract cannot be changed after deployment. Please I need enlightening regarding it.

This also depends on the specific implementation. A smart contract could have a function that lets the deployer stop or change the amount of burning (which wouldn't be decentralized at all).